# Can I gather information (like email addresses) from flow initiator when launching flow in Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate

I'm trying to set up a flow in Power Automate that allows the initiator to add data that will be used within the flow when they start the flow.  For example, can I have an field where the initiator can input email addresses of those who should receive a notification that the document is ready for review?

I know that I could pull from another column in the document library with this information.  But I'm not wanting to store this information in a column.  I would like it asked when the flow is initiated in Power Automate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done when the flow is triggered for the selected item or document. (Also for a manually triggered flow, but you are talking about SharePoint libraries, so I'll focus on that.)

In the Flow portal, create a new flow with "Instant > From Blank". Then in the dialog where you choose how to trigger this flow, select "For a selected file" and click **Create**.

[image]

In the initiation action, specify the site address and library name, then click **Add an input**. 
The "Email" option is really a people picker control. When the flow is launched you can only select people from your tenant. The other options should be self-explanatory.

[image]

You can then find the input name in the dynamic content picker for subsequent actions.

[image]

When you publish the flow, you need to define the Run-Only users on the flow details page. These people will then see the flow in the "Automate" menu on their SharePoint command bar when a single document is selected.

Comment: I'd completely missed the "Choose the type of user input" section on my initiation step.  That's what I needed!